# Django optimize waiting for a response

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-views, python-asyncio

I'm trying to speed up my Django server which is running let's say 4 processes and for some view, it is making a request to another server which is performing some computation and sending a request to another server. Which is taking a very long time to respond let's say 5 minutes, in that case, my server will get stuck after 4 requests in a short period of time. How can I optimize it, I believe it is due to busy waiting for the request, is it possible to respond to other requests and finish replying to that request after the response from another server. I believe the solution for that is async view in Django, but do I have to convert the whole view or can I convert just the function calling the external server?

Answer (score 0):

To optimise your Django server and prevent it from getting stuck while waiting for responses from slow external servers, you can indeed use asynchronous views in Django. The purpose of async views is to allow your server to handle multiple requests concurrently and continue processing other requests while waiting for responses.

In this case, you can convert just the function calling the external server to an asynchronous function, without necessarily converting the entire view. This approach enables your server to respond to other requests while waiting for the response from the slow external server.

Here's an example to illustrate how you can convert the specific function calling the external server to an asynchronous function:

```
import asyncio
from django.http import JsonResponse

async def external_server_request():
    # Perform your long-running request to the external server
    await asyncio.sleep(300)  # Simulating a long response time

def your_view(request):
    # Perform your regular processing

    # Start the asynchronous task to make the request to the external server
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(external_server_request())

# Continue processing other tasks while waiting for the response
# ...

# Check if the task is complete
if task.done():
    # If the task is complete, get the result
    result = task.result()
    # Process the result

# Continue with the remaining processing and return the response
data = {
    'message': 'Request processed successfully!',
    # ...
}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

In this example, the external_server_request function is an asynchronous function that simulates a long-running request to the external server using asyncio.sleep(). In your view, you start the asynchronous task using loop.create_task() to make the request to the external server. This allows your server to continue processing other tasks while waiting for the response.

You can then check if the task is complete using the task.done() method. If the task is complete, you can retrieve the result using task.result() and process it accordingly. Afterward, you can continue with the remaining processing and return the response to the client.

By converting just the function calling the external server to an asynchronous function, you can effectively handle multiple requests concurrently and ensure that your server doesn't get stuck while waiting for slow responses.

Or you can also try with [workers](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/job-queues-workers-django/) in django